# Is it possible to flag a chat message "for moderator attention" (w/ explanation box) from transcript?

Tags: support, chat, chat-flags

When you click the flag button on a message in the chat window, it reads "flag for moderator", and a dialog with an explanation field pops up.

When you click the flag button on a message in the transcript or on the star wall, it reads "flag as spam/offensive" and the flag is immediately raised.

Is it possible to raise a "moderator" style flag (with the explanation) from the transcript if it is no longer in the current chat window?

---

It seems it can somewhat be done by repeatedly clicking "load older messages" in the chat window until the message in question is in view and flagging from there; is there an easier way?

Comment: I don't know chat at all, but obviously a workaround if one doesn't exist in chat would be to find one of the user's post on the main/meta site and use a "mod attention" flag, and explain there.

Comment: I feel like this used to work. Perhaps I'm wrong, but I remember flagging something "for moderator attention" from the transcript once... but you're right, now you can't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not conveniently.

The primary use of chat flags is to address an issue that is currently ongoing - for instance, a disruptive user or ongoing offensive messages.

If you can't find the message in the current window, there's a good chance the message has passed and no action need be taken anyway.

However, in the event that something serious needs to be erased from chat history, you can use the search box to find it. Feel free to flag any message with a link and description, or just ping a moderator if it's safe to bring attention to publicly.